# Why is it not possible to inherit a public class from an internal class?

Tags: c#

See this code:

```
internal class c 
{
    private int d;
}

public class a : c
{
    private int b;
}
```

Why can I not inherit a public class from an internal class? Why does the compiler have this behavior?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/11/13/why-is-deriving-a-public-class-from-an-internal-class-illegal.aspx

Comment: @SLaks: You should probably post this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the public class would be visible outside your current assembly, while the internal one isn't. When deriving from a class you can only *restrict* visibility further, because in your case it would make the implementation of `c` available to consumers outside your assembly which kind of defeats the purpose of making the class internal in the first place.

You *can* use composition instead of inheritance, though.

Answer (score 2):

C# design principle. Derived class should atleast have same accessibility as the parent class. In your case it is not hence not allowed. Take a look at Eric Lippert's view on this [deriving public class from an internal class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/11/13/why-is-deriving-a-public-class-from-an-internal-class-illegal.aspx)

Comment: less visible or **as visible**.

Comment: thanks Rotem for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Because "public class" is more "visible" than "internal class".

C# language has visibility protection layer that prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

Internal classes can only be accessed from within the Assembly in which they are defined. When public class a inherits from an internal class in effect attempts to make the internal class public.

To avoid this encapsulate the internal class in the public class.